# Clickonce - Publishing Application via FTP but not using default port 21

Tags: c#-4.0, ftp, clickonce

Our web server uses port 3434 for FTP. It doesn't seem to change the default FTP port number in ClickOnce Deployment in Visual Studio. Has anyone encountered this problem?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that I just needed to add port number after the IP address like `ftp://1.123.123.123:3434`